# Using Streams instead of for loop in java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

```
int [] numbers = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
int [] doubleNumbers = new int[numbers.length];
int [] tripleNumbers = new int[numbers.length];


for(int index = 0; index < numbers.length; index++)
{
    doubleNumbers[index] = numbers[index] * 2;  
    tripleNumbers[index] = numbers[index] * 3;
}

System.out.println("Double Numbers");
Arrays.stream(doubleNumbers).forEach(System.out::println);

System.out.println("Triple Numbers");
Arrays.stream(tripleNumbers).forEach(System.out::println);
```

I have above code where I have used for loop and double and triple the numbers and stored it in different arrays in single loop. Can anybody help me to write the same code using streams with its map and other methods without iterating numbers array twice.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
IntStream.range(0, numbers.length)
  .forEach(index -> {
    doubleNumbers[index] = numbers[index] * 2;
    tripleNumbers[index] = numbers[index] * 3;
  });
```

Answer (score 7):

You can apply the doubling and tripling within the stream:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};

    System.out.println("Double Numbers");
    Arrays.stream(numbers).map(x -> x * 2).forEach(System.out::println);

    System.out.println("Triple Numbers");
    Arrays.stream(numbers).map(x -> x * 3).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

though technically that's still iterating over the array twice.

As a trick you could instead collect the results in a `Map`:

```java
Map<Integer, Integer> m = Arrays.stream(numbers)
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                x -> x * 2,
                x -> x * 3
        ));
```

Comment: Yes Jon thats right its simpler and clean approach that i am aware of but yes i am expecting to iteration of array only once

Comment: @SarangShinde I've edited my answer to add another solution which avoids iterating over the array twice.

Comment: Iterating twice shouldn’t be a problem as the question’s code is iterating *three* times, so the error is already in the question. Accepting an answer that “solves” this by simply omitting one of the two requested results (besides changing “times” to “power”), is quite strange.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like your question is more complicated than just using Java Stream API. The better way is define some wrapper class like `Num.class`:

```java
class Num {
    private final int value;

    //constructor

    public int powerOf(int index) {
        return Math.pow(value, index);
    }
}
```

Then you can just wrap your array elements into this object and call `powerOf` method where you need. With your implementation you are creating unnecessary arrays for keeping powered values. And using Stream API in this case is more convinient:

```java
Arrays.stream(numbers).map(Num::new)
        .forEach(n -> System.out.println("power of 2": + n.powerOf(2));
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response and different view on same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stream` with `forEach` method to populate `collections` of doubles and triples e.g.:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] numbers = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    List<Integer> doubles = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> triples = new ArrayList<>();

    Arrays.stream(numbers)
    .boxed()
    .forEach(n -> {
        doubles.add(n*2);
        triples.add(n*3);
        }
    );

    System.out.println(doubles);
    System.out.println(triples);
}
```

Another example with `map` and `collect`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] numbers = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};

    List<Integer> doubles = Arrays.stream(numbers)
    .boxed()
    .map(n -> n*2)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

    List<Integer> triples = Arrays.stream(numbers)
            .boxed()
            .map(n -> n*3)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(doubles);
    System.out.println(triples);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can represent each *number* as a string array of *double* and *triple* numbers, and then output those arrays using a single stream:

```java
int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};

Arrays.stream(numbers)
        // represent each number as a string
        // array of double and triple numbers
        // Stream<String[]>
        .mapToObj(i -> new String[]{
                String.valueOf(i * 2),
                String.valueOf(i * 3)})
        // reduce a stream of arrays to a single array
        .reduce((arr1, arr2) -> new String[]{
                // concatenate double numbers
                arr1[0] + " " + arr2[0],
                // concatenate triple numbers
                arr1[1] + " " + arr2[1]
        }) // output values if present
        .ifPresent(arr -> {
            System.out.println("Double numbers: " + arr[0]);
            System.out.println("Triple numbers: " + arr[1]);
        });
```

Output:

```
Double numbers: 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16
Triple numbers: 3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24
```

---

<sup>See also: [Generate all possible string combinations by replacing the hidden `#` number sign](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65975106/15309136)</sup>