# How to iterate only through the first row of a 2d array?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I have a beginner question.

How do I iterate through only the first row of an two dimensional array in Java?

For example, if I have:

```java
int[][] array = {{5, 22, 30, 40, 30}, {96, 20, 30, 25, 25}};
```

How do I only iterate through `{5, 22, 30, 40, 30}` or `{96, 20, 30, 25, 25}`?

Answer (score 0):

In JAVA 2D array means `1D array of 1D arrays`; i.e. each row is the separate 1D array (therefore they can have different sizes).

`int[][] arr = new int[2][3]` means that you have created 2D arrays with `2` rows and `3` columns in each row. Rows and columns are **zero-indices**, so to get access to the first row, you should use `0` index.

```java
int[][] array = {{5, 22, 30, 40, 30}, {96, 20, 30, 25, 25}};

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array[0]));    // {5, 22, 30, 40, 30}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array[1]));    // {96, 20, 30, 25, 25}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

The first square brackets it's for ¿Wich array you are looking for? `{5, 22, 30, 40, 30}`  [0] or `{96, 20, 30, 25, 25}` [1] ?

Then, the second square brackets are for: ¿Wich element inside the array are you looking for? To retrieve the 22 of `{5, 22, 30, 40, 30}`  you sould use [0] [1], [menaing First array] and [second element of array choosen].

**Edit**

You need 2 `for` cicles to iterate all the elements:

```
for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {    
    for (int col = 0; col < array[row].length; col++) {
       System.Out.Println(array[row][col]);
    }
}
```

Source [here](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2015/09/how-to-loop-two-dimensional-array-in-java.html#ixzz6oAqTw6mh)

**Edit #2**
To iterate only for the first array, burn the first square bracket to [0]:

```
for (int col = 0; col < array[0].length; col++) {
       System.Out.Println(array[0][col]); // Iterating only the first array elements.
    }
```

Comment: Thanks very much. This saves my time. But Please check this "System.Out.Println(array[0][col])" will throw an error. it's rather System.out.println(array[0][col]) is the appropriate one for the sake of us the beginners. I stand to be corrected

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Stream` for this purpose:

```java
int[][] array = {{5, 22, 30, 40, 30}, {96, 20, 30, 25, 25}};

System.out.println(Arrays.stream(array[0])
        .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" "))); //5 22 30 40 30

System.out.println(Arrays.stream(array[1])
        .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" "))); //96 20 30 25 25
```

---

<sup>See also: [Using Streams instead of for loop in java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66516302/15309136)</sup>